# SimpleXML Redirection Limit Reached

Tags: php, simplexml

I am trying to open an XML file on a remote server, but I get an error that says the redirection limit is reached. I have no control over the remote, so is there a way that I can increase that limit? Or, should I talk to the person who owns the server and see what they can do?

This is the error:

> Warning:
>   simplexml_load_file(http://www.server.com/search/music.xml?key=key&type=songs&p1=All%20Things%20New&p2=Elevation%20Worship)
>   [function.simplexml-load-file]: failed to open stream: Redirection
>   limit reached, aborting in /home/admin/public_html/art/art.php on
>   line 4
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: I/O
>   warning : failed to load external entity
>   "http://www.server.com/search/music.xml?key=key&type=songs&p1=All%20Things%20New&p2=Elevation%20Worship"
>   in /home/admin/public_html/art/art.php on line 4
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function xpath() on a non-object in
>   /home/admin/public_html/art/art.php on line 6

My code is:

```
<?php
function errorHandler($n, $m, $f, $l) {
    header('Location: blank.png');
}

set_error_handler('errorHandler');

$url = 'http://REMOTESERVER/search/music.xml?key=KEY&type=songs&p1=' . htmlspecialchars($_GET["track"]) . '&p2=' . htmlspecialchars($_GET["artist"]) . '';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

$img = $xml->xpath('//image200');

$large = (string)$img[0];

header("Location:".urldecode($large));
?>
```

Comment: Where do you get that error? From the connection or from simplexml? Have you tried accessing the faulty url in your browser? Does it show there? If not, yes ask the owner :).

Comment: I added the error messages to the question.

Comment: Also, when I copy the XML file from the remote server and save it on mine, it works.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're seeing is not to do with SimpleXML as such, it is PHP's transparent remote file access mechanism which is complaining. You can verify this by creating a simpler test case using `file_get_contents($url);` [`simplexml_load_file($url)` is basically short-hand for `simplexml_load_string( file_get_contents($url) )`]

That specific error message indicates that the URL you are trying to load is serving an HTTP redirect (status code `301`, `302`) to forward to another URL, which is then forwarding to another, and so on. Either there is a long chain of these, or the remote server has been misconfigured so that it's creating an infinite loop.

Note that such a redirect may be conditional on attributes of the request, so loading it in your browser may not behave quite the same way. If it does, though, you should be able to see it in the Net panel of browser debug tools such as Firebug.

Possible solutions:

- work out what the final URL is supposed to be and request that, rather than the start of the redirect chain
- ask the maintainer of the remote server to check their configuration and reduce the number of chained redirects
- use PHP's [cURL functions](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to explicitly fetch the data rather than treating the URL as a filename; this will give you complete control over options such as redirect handling, but is obviously a bit more fiddly to get right